# How is CheckBox with multi-line text done in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, multiline

How do I extend the text in a Windows Forms [CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to more than one line?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use `\r\n` in order to add a new line. You might have to do this in the code behind. So your code would be like this:

```
myLabel.Text = "New\r\nLine\r\nExample";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. And you're right it only works in code not in the designer

Comment: You can use the designer: click the drop-down arrow on the right hand edge of the Text line to get the multi-line text editor

Comment: There is no more drop-down arrow in VS 2017. I've found strange behavior in the Designer. Setting AutoSize to: False did nothing. Only after I've changed "AutoEllipsis" to different value (from True to False or vice versa) it started working as multiline.

Answer (score 11):

First you should turn autosize property to False.
Then resize the box and use \r\n for going to next line.

Comment: No need to have AutoSize to False, no need for escaped characters... if you're using the forms editor then do it directly using the drop-down arrow on the right of the text field