# one item 2 lines checkbox list c#

Tags: c#

I wanted to have a list of checkbox items in a string collection editor, but one of the item is too long so I wanted it to put in a newline.

My list goes like this
*Sleeveless, halters, tube, strapless, backless
*Spaghetti straps, plunging necklines, and like
*Tight fitting, blouses and dresses
*Beach clothes, blouses which do not cover the mid-body parts
*Short dresses and skirts that are more than two(2) inches above the middle of the knee

But I wanted to be like this

*Sleeveless, halters, tube, strapless, backless
*Spaghetti straps, plunging necklines, and like
*Tight fitting, blouses and dresses
*Beach clothes, blouses which do not cover the mid-body parts
*Short dresses and skirts that are more than two(2) inches
above the middle of the knee

I want the last item to be in 2 lines but only count as one item, cause I know if you put it in a new line it will count as another item. Thanks. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the text of checkbox wraps automatically with changing form width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588506/how-can-i-make-the-text-of-checkbox-wraps-automatically-with-changing-form-width)

Comment: Checkboxlist doesn't have an autosize properties. only the checkbox.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could specify which UI framework you are using here. The answer will vary accordingly.

Comment: I'm using visual studio. c#

Comment: Yes but a web project? WPF? Winforms? Silverlight? The list goes on and on!

Comment: Winforms.............

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using asp.net webform. I have checked only against the bigger text from your example. Check below html code for your reference.

```
[![<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
    .checkboxlist_nowrap tr td label
    {
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style> 
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="border: solid 1px blue; width:300px">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="line 0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="*Short dresses and skirts that are more than two(2) inches above the middle of the knee "></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

Comment: Do you truly know if he's using ASP.net?

Comment: @NahuelIanni, No, but this is what I have assumed. Anyway thanku for pointing I will update my answer :)